# How to send non-alphanumeric keys through Katalon

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I'm trying to send a backspace key in Katalon to my web application. I know how send a string.

```
    //this works
    WebUI.sendKeys(to, '50.00')

    //This doesn't work
    WebUI.sendKeys(to, Keys.Backspace)
```

This didn't work as keys.backspace isn't a string, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Keys.chord() function. For example:

```
WebUI.sendKeys(to, Keys.chord(Keys.BACK_SPACE))
```

Hope that helps.